# Procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in kernel32.dll

Tags: windows, windows-xp, dll, service-pack

I get this error when trying to run a program on a Windows computer:

[image]

Because it's a Dutch Windows version it is in Dutch, but in English it would be something like "Procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in kernel32.dll".

I've been looking for a solution on the net and I think it has something to do with SP's of Windows. This are the system settings:

[image]

Does this mean I'm not using any Windows XP Service Pack? I'm working on this for someone else, it's an old computer, not connected to the internet.

Should I connect the computer to the internet and install all Windows updates to solve the problem? No other solution?

Comment: Finally got the time to try installing SP3, got an error message: I first have to install SP1 or SP2. Yes, this computer has even no SP1! (it's not mine)

Comment: i add the following for searchability. in English (US), the error reads precisely as follows: "The procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll" the alternative version (with *decode* in place of *encode*) also happens: "The procedure entry point DecodePointer could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, EncodePointer was introduced in Windows XP service pack 2, so it is very likely that the reason the software is not working is that you do not have this installed.  However, this doesn't mean you need to hook the computer to the internet.

Instead, use another computer to download [service pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24) and put it on CD or USB stick.  Copy it to the hard disk of the target computer, then run it.  You probably don't need any of the other updates.

(Note: ignore the bit on the download page that says "This installation package is intended for IT professionals ... please visit Windows Update".  In this situation, this package is the simplest way of installing the service pack, even for a single computer, and the process isn't particularly difficult.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sounds very good, I will give it a try. But is there any risk by installing SP3? I mean the computer "won't work anymore". Should I make a backup before installing SP3?

Comment: You should always make a backup first.  But the risk is minimal.