# Download Service Pack 2 for Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Where can I download SP2? I have this problem: [Procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in kernel32.dll](https://superuser.com/questions/433305/), but I first have to install SP2 before I can install SP3. No, computer is not connected to the internet so I can't use Windows Update.

Comment: I suggest you download a Windows XP SP3 iso so you will have the current installation.  I assume you have a method of doing this.

Comment: Yes, but you can't install SP3 if no SP is installed at all, so first SP1 or SP2

Comment: `Where can I download SP2? No, computer is not connected to the internet so I can't use Windows Update.`   ‽‽‽ If you cannot use Windows Update because of a lack of Internet connection, then how can you *download* SP2? `o.O` Are you (implying) that you intend to use a secondary system and burn the SP2 installation to a disc or flash-drive? That is pretty much the only thing that makes sense (in which case, you would of course need the network/admin installer).

Comment: I downloaded the SP on another computer, put in on a USB flash drive and installed in at the computer without internet connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Windows XP Service Pack 2 Network Installation Package from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28). FYI, it is 266MB so bring a USB drive or blank CD if you are going to move it from another computer.

Also, the [Service Pack Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/service-packs) is where you can find the latest, as well as older versions, of service packs for your particular version of Windows.

Comment: (While you are at it you might want to include SP1 & SP3 just for future reference, then change title of question so it's not so specific)

Comment: added that info